# Exporting Gridview to excel without gridlines

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, export, asp.net-2.0

I use this code to export datagridview to excel

```
HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
string fileName = "TRAIL" + "[" + DatefromTxtBox.Text.Replace("/", "") + "_" + DatetoTxtBox.Text.Replace("/", "") + "]" + ".xls";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
AuditTrailGV.AllowPaging = false;
AuditTrailGV.DataSource = (DataSet)ViewState["audit"];
AuditTrailGV.DataBind();
form.Controls.Add(AuditTrailGV);
this.Controls.Add(form);
form.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

the problem is this code also catches the formatting/borders of my gridview

here are the sample screen shots

This is my gridview in asp.net
[image]

and this is what appears in my excell
[image]

as you can see it transformed all of the lines like the gridview, i do not want it to happen, as much as possible if i can only retain the gridlines for the rows with data only, if its not possible, remove all the gridlines..

any help? i really do not like those gridlines in my excell

Answer (score 1):

VB

```
Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control As Control)
    'base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
    'This remains empty
End Sub

Protected Sub btnExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnExcel.Click

    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

    Dim stringWrite As New System.IO.StringWriter()
    Dim htmlWrite As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)

    htmlWrite.Write("<html xmlns:o=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"" ")
    htmlWrite.Write("xmlns:x=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"" ")
    htmlWrite.Write("xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40""> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("<head> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:Selected/> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("</xml><![endif]--> ")
    htmlWrite.Write("</head>")
    htmlWrite.WriteLine("")

    gridView.HeaderStyle.Reset()
    gridView.FooterStyle.Reset()
    gridView.AlternatingRowStyle.Reset()
    gridView.RowStyle.Reset()

    gridView.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    gridView.GridLines = GridLines.None
    gridView.RenderControl(htmlWrite)

    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString())
    Response.[End]()
End Sub
```

C#

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    //base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
    //This remains empty
}


protected void btnExcel_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    htmlWrite.Write("<html xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" ");
    htmlWrite.Write("xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\" ");
    htmlWrite.Write("xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("<head> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:Name>Sheet1</x:Name> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:Selected/> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("<x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("</xml><![endif]--> ");
    htmlWrite.Write("</head>");
    htmlWrite.WriteLine("");

    gridView.HeaderStyle.Reset();
    gridView.FooterStyle.Reset();
    gridView.AlternatingRowStyle.Reset();
    gridView.RowStyle.Reset();

    gridView.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    gridView.GridLines = GridLines.None;
    gridView.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code and custom the color of the downloaded data. It will also not color the Column and rows other then the data.

```
protected void DownloadExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Report.xls"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "#bfc2c7");
    }

    int j = 1;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
    {           
        //gvrow.BackColor = color.White;
        if (j <= GridView1.Rows.Count)
        {
            if (j % 2 != 0)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < gvrow.Cells.Count; k++)
                {
                    gvrow.Cells[k].Style.Add("background-color", "#EFF3FB");    
                }
            }
        }
        j++;
    }
    GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: still the same as the second picture in my question.